# service worker fetch event on first load

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

i am trying to learn some basics of progressive web apps and on one of the tutorial regarding i read that

[After a service worker is installed and the user navigates to a different page or refreshes, the service worker will begin to receive fetch events]

my question is can't we make the fetch event to take place on first load of index page itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `self.clients.claim()` inside *activate* event listener, which allows the loaded service worker to set itself as the active worker for a client page.

You can read more about this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim), and check out current browsers' compatibility [here](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/)

Comment: Are you sure? Because I am using self.clients.claim() and  I am not getting this behaviour

Comment: I take back my previous comment. I was doing self.clients.claim() but I was doing it within a .then after a event.waitUntil within the activate. I moved self.clients.claim() to the entry start of the event.waitUntil and moved the old cache removal to a .then off of the claim. This seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @DanTheNorthernCodeMonkey Can you give the result example?